# Outlook Email Attachment Save Permissions

Tags: vba, outlook

This Excel VBA code is supposed to loop through my Outlook folder inbox-> Work Request.
Then for each mail item in that folder, download each attachment and save it to a file location.

Code finds the folder and the emails.

I tried multiple save locations including our external cloud drive and my personal desktop. Currently the code is saving to my desktop and says

> Run-Time Error '-2147024891(80070005) Cannot save the attachment. You don't have the appropriate permissions to perform this operation.

on the following line

```
olAtt.SaveAsFile ("C:\Users\John Smith\Desktop\WOR Email Download")
```

The rest of the code is below.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Download_Outlook_Attachemtns()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olItem As Object
Dim MailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim FileLocation As String

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'single folder link to hidden sheet folders([admin].[Mailbox].text)
Set olFolder = olNS.Folders("JohnSmith@work.com")
Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("Inbox")
Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("Work Requests")

For Each olItem In olFolder.Items

    If olItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set MailItem = olItem
        'Debug.Print MailItem.Subject

        For Each olAtt In MailItem.Attachments
            If MailItem.ReceivedTime > ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Email_Info").Range("C6").Value Then
                olAtt.SaveAsFile ("C:\Users\John Smith\Desktop\WOR Email Download")
                'olAtt.SaveAs Filename:=Application.GetSaveAsFilename
            End If
        Next olAtt
        
    End If
Next olItem

'Set olFolder = Nothing
'Set olNS = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to use a complete valid path for _SaveAsFile_ (including file name and file extension)

Comment: Take a look at previous posts. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52867486/unable-to-download-files-from-outlook-with-vba and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996356/macro-error-cannot-save-the-attachment-dont-have-appropriate-permission. If successful, consider upvoting an answer. If not successful, list your attempts and the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, instead of iterating over all items in the folder:

```
For Each olItem In olFolder.Items

    If olItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set MailItem = olItem
```

You can find all items with attachments in the folder and iterate over them only. The `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class do the magic. Read more about these methods in the articles I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

For example, you can use the following search criteria (VBA syntax):

```
Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" & Chr(34) & "=1"
```

Also it makes sense to optimize the code by changing the order of conditions:

```
For Each olAtt In MailItem.Attachments
        If MailItem.ReceivedTime > ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Email_Info").Range("C6").Value Then
```

Instead of checking the received time of the email for each attachment you can check it once for the email before iterating over attached files or, better yet, you may include another condition to the search criteria by using the logical AND operator in the search string.

Finally, you may try to check the [Attachment.Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.type) property value before trying to save anything to the disk. The property returns an `OlAttachmentType` constant indicating the type of the specified object.

Comment: Wow very helpful and detail I appreciate this

Answer (score 0):

You *must* include the file name besides the folder name. Currently, you are telling Outlook to save to a file conflicting with an existing folder name ("WOR Email Download"), hence the "no access" error - the file cannot be created since its name conflicts with an existing folder name. Change your code to

```
if olAtt.Type = olByValue Then
  olAtt.SaveAsFile "C:\Users\John Smith\Desktop\WOR Email Download\" & olAtt.FileName
End If
```